# Facebook cloud integration

Tags: facebook, heroku

Hey I have been practicing developing facebook applications on heroku cloud.Today when I check it is seen that facebook-heroku tie up has been dicontinued.What do I do now?Is there some other way to deploy my apps to facebook or is there any way that I can continue with heroku as my cloud provider?Thanks in advance